# How to get specific object-elements from JSON-array into JavaScript-array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have an external JSON-file. It looks like this:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
"totalFeatures":1,
"features":
    [{ 
    "type":"Feature",
    "id":"asdf",
    "geometry":null,
    "properties":
        {
        "PARAM1":"19 16 11",
        "PARAM2":"31 22 11",
        "PARAM3":"12 10 7",
        }
    }],
"crs":null
}`
```

As I think "*features*" is an JSON-array and "*properties*" an object of this array.
I stuck at trying to "*push*" the element "*PARAM1*" into another array in my JS-code.
My attempt was to get the data via jQuery AJAX. It looks like this:

```
function (){
var arrPARAM1 = new Array ();
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'gew.json',
    data: "",
    accepts:'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        arrPARAM1.push(data.features);
    }
})
console.log(arrPARAM1);
}
```

With *arrPARAM1.push(data.features)* I can "*push*" the whole array "*features*" into my JS-array. But I only want to have the element "*PARAM1*" from the object "*properties*". How can I get deeper (*features* --> *properties* --> *PARAM1*)?

Thanks for your attention!

---

SOLUTION:

```
arrPARAM1.push(data.features[0].properties.PARAM1);
```

Comment: never set async to false....its even deprecated (and has been for awhile)

Answer (score 4):

It's just an array with a single element so access `[0]` then `.properties`

```
arrPARAM1.push(data.features[0].properties.PARAM1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be looking for something like this:

`data.features[0].properties["PARAM1"]`

Or

`data.features[0].properties.PARAM1`

Answer (score 0):

You defined features as an array so when you access is, you must treat it as an array.

```
arrPARAM1.push(data.features[0].properties.PARAM1); //gets param1 from the features array
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple features:

```
data.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    arrPARAM1.push(feature.properties.PARAM1);
})
```